# Protractor: Click on SVG element not work

Tags: angularjs, testing, svg, protractor, end-to-end

I am testing an angularjs App using protractor.

I need to test the click on an SVG element.

Protractor can find the element, it can run the click on the element, but after the click nothing happens.

It should change page after the click.

The code is

```
el=element(by.xpath('(//*[local-name()="g" ]//*[local-name() = "rect"])[1]'))
    browser.actions().mouseMove(el.getWebElement()).click().perform();
```

Comment: What is `el`? What happens on `el.click()`? Can you also make a reproducible example demonstrating the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Just create an svg (e.g. take a demo of highcharts library, copy and paste it into an ng-app, and then you are done), and test this on it.

`el` is element(by.xpath('(//*[local-name()="g" ]//*[local-name() = "rect"])[1]')).

I edited the question with what el is

Answer (score 0):

I agree with what @alecxe suggested in his comment. You should be calling `click()` on the element itself:

```
var el = element(by.xpath('(//*[local-name()="g" ]//*[local-name() = "rect"])[1]'));
el.click();
```

Comment: Any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

This is still an issue. According to github issues browser.actions() should be used. Following solution finally worked out for me:

```
await browser.driver.actions().mouseMove(element(by.css('YOUR_LOCATOR')).getWebElement()).perform();
await browser.actions().click().perform();
```

https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/2272

https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/4495