# Unable to click on SVG element using Selenium

Tags: selenium, svg, xpath

I am trying to automate the Edit portion of LinkedIn Profile. I see that the pen icon for editing my profile is an SVG element and I am unable to locate it using XPATH. Can some one help transforming the XPATH to SVG format so that I can use that ?

Also would appreciate if any proper documentation of the same can be provided. Thanks in advance.

I am using the general XPATH for clicking the icon:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//svg[@class='artdeco-icon']")).click;
```

Screenshot URL : https://www.screencast.com/t/d21Ap1XsMVt

Error Log link : https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-gsMUPbAIhxQTJiSXViZTZlelU

Comment: You can check out this link (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41829000/selenium-webdriver-java-how-to-click-on-elements-within-an-svg-using-xpath) which might help you. Else let me know we will help you out. Thanks

Comment: @Dev : Following your link, but wasn't able to understand how to frame the path. Could you please help ? 
So the idea is to click the SVG Element [Pen Icon per the screenshot] :   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//svg[@class='artdeco-icon']")).click; is what I find as the xpath.

Thanks

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30940736/protractor-click-on-svg-element-not-work. there are other threads also where this question is already answer. please search them.

Comment: Can be specific please about the binding you are using Java/Python/C#/Ruby/JS ?

Comment: Can you update me the manual steps you want to perform once you login to the site?

Comment: Steps : 
1. Login to LinkedIn.
2. Go to Your Profile 
3. Click on the pen icon as shown in the screenshot : https://www.screencast.com/t/d21Ap1XsMVt 

Here is where the issue is. I am unable to click on the icon. I am using Java.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Protractor: Click on SVG element not work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30940736/protractor-click-on-svg-element-not-work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below `XPath` expression to match required icon:

```
//span[text()="Edit Profile"]/following::*[local-name()="svg"]
```

Comment: @Anderson : Please check the xpath I have shared. I don't see a span anywhere.

Comment: But it there:) On LinkedIn page. Did you try my `XPath`?

Comment: Yeah found it, Anderson! Thanks a lot. Solved my problem.

Comment: @Andersson I think if you take a closer look you don't even need to access the SVG elements as well :) my solution is much simpler

Comment: @Dev, Using direct link could also be acceptable, but it's not *much simpler* :) Using indexes for several elements in `XPath` is bad practice

Comment: Well but your xpath fetches me 17 results :)

Comment: But only first one (the required one) will be chosen :)

Comment: @Andersson Remember how you helped me out of the woods with unique xpath of svg elements :) that too contained indexes

Comment: That was exceptional case :) I had limited amount of options

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution of your Question-

If your testing step is to click the pencil icon to edit your profile, you need to have a closer look into the HTML DOM. The pencil icon is not within any SVG element.

You can click on the pencil icon through:

`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='core-rail']/section[1]/a[1]")).click();`

Let me know if this Answers your Question.